# SoapUI Auth Header with special characters

Tags: authentication, base64, soapui

I am using SoapUI and encountered that if I add `umlauts` into the password, it does not work as expected.

Here is an example: Lets assume as username `"täst"` and as password `"!23Öüok"`. SoapUI will create the following Base64 encoded String:  `"Authorization: Basic dD9zdDohMjM/P29r[\r][\n]"`. Decoding `"dD9zdDohMjM/P29r"` will result into this `"t?st:!23??ok"`.

Is there any SoapUI specific setting or anything that I am missing? I think the Base64 encoded String should be like this: `"dMOkc3Q6ITIzw5bDvG9r"`

Comment: What is your operating system? Can you show the data from `Menu -> Help -> System Properties`? Please update the question.

Comment: How about other part of the above request?

Comment: Which further information do you need? The encoding ist Cp1252.

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Please see the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you need to have have encoding as `UTF-8` in order to see the desired value.

- Go to `SOAPUI_HOME/bin`
- Have a backup of soapui.bat file
- Close soapui tool if it is running
- Open soapui.bat in a text editor of your choice
- Find line `set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dsoapui.ext.libraries="%SOAPUI_HOME%ext"`
- Add below line after the above line
  `set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`
- Save the file
- Restart soapui, make sure that is reflected in System Properties

This should help you to see the desired output.

Note that if you are using `testrunner.bat` to execute the tests, incorporate the above suggested change into this file as well.